# A word for changing shape/size?

Tags: single-word-requests

For an assignment this term I have to come up with an anti-cliché superhero. I am going to do a superhero that changes shape from thin to big and was wondering if anyone knew a word for this change of shape/size.

Comment: I'm afraid that your superhero isn't really going against the grain. [Metamorpho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamorpho) is a pretty well known character. There are [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_superhuman_features_and_abilities_in_fiction#Shapeshifting) too. The [Superhero database](http://www.superherodb.com/powers/Shapeshifting/) might also be of some assistance.

Comment: Calvin and Hobbes might suggest *transmogrify*.

Comment: @coleopterist Well, he did say cliché :)
Aaaah... anti-cliché... Hm. Maybe he was making a joke :P

Comment: See also [Marvel's Big Bertha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bertha_(comics))

Comment: Off topic: naming a superhero (disguised as a word request).

Comment: Great question cdavi! +1

Answer (score 7):

Consider *[protean](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/protean)*, "Exceedingly variable; readily assuming different shapes or forms";  "From Ancient Greek Πρωτεύς (Prōteus), the Greek warden of sea beasts, renowned for his ability to change shape."

Answer (score 4):

Morph, metamorphose and mutate immediately come to mind ... And if he's changing the shape/size (in a negative way) of another object, mutilate.

Comment: That would be _mutate_ and not _mutilate_.

Comment: You missed a spot :) Also, mutate isn't necessarily negative.

Comment: Mutilate is. I meant to keep that mutilate. Mutate refers to changing oneself... you can't mutate something else, can you? And I see that mutate can be used transitively... can you give an example? I couldn't think of any.

Comment: I would suggest "transmute" over "mutate" in this context.

Comment: I liked transmute :) But I feel mutate sounds better. I dunno...

Comment: @asymptotically Rather than asking me, ask the entire community ;)

Comment: intransitive: "It will mutate". transitive: "It will mutate me".

Comment: Ready Kafka?!?!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want a synonym for horizontal expansion (like *puff* or *pop*) more than you want a word for shapeshifting, since your superhero's morph abilities seem pretty specific and limited.

In any case, an anti-cliché superhero ought to have an anti-cliché name. How about **Mister McPuffins** (his tumescence is swell!)?  Or Mary Poppins's cousin **Percival Poppins**?

Answer (score 3):

Following Urbycoz’s gist, how about *SupersizeMan*? ([def. *supersize*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supersize))

In a more humdrum vein, to increase in size is to *augment*, and *Augmentor* has a kind of X-men feel to it.

Answer (score 2):

A "superhero that changes shape from thin to big"?

Dinna dinna dinna dinna...

> **[Bloat](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bloat)-man!!!**

Answer (score 1):

***Inflatoman*** might fill the bill, but could conjur up old superheros such as the *StaPuft Marshmallow man* from Ghost Busters, the *Michelin Man*, or even the *Charles Atlas skinny-to-stud beach bodybuilder*.

Answer (score 0):

Your superhero appears to be changing from an [*ectomorph*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectomorphic) to an [*endomorph*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphic), so you could do something based on that.

Endomorpher?  Endomorpho?

To answer the more general aspects of your question, the basic term for changing shape is *metamorphosis*.  Which also means that names based on the body types noted above have a useful intrinsic allusion in place.

Answer (score 0):

You could use words like *shape-shifting*, *amoebic*, *elastic*, or *mutable*. You could also use *pliable* to describe an inanimate object with the properties of your aforementioned superhero.

Answer (score 0):

In general you would call it *transforming*. More specifically, *dilating*,  *scaling*, or simply *growing* or *enlarging*

That said, the ability to grow or shrink oneself isn't particularly "anti-cliche".